# Symfony2 - Reset form field after submission

Tags: php, forms, symfony

I wonder whether there is a simple way to reset one of the form fields after form submission and then pass the form to the view - to render the same form but one of the field will be with it's default value. Something like:

```
$form = $this->createForm('MyForm');
$form->handleRequest($request);
if ($form->isValid()) {
    // do something
    // ...

    // reset one of the form field to it's default value
    // something like:
    // $form->field->reset() or
    // $form->field->setValue('');
}

return array(
    'form' => $form->createView(),
);
```

Thanks!

Comment: Add `'always_empty' => true` to configureOptions of your form.

Comment: I want to reset just one of the form fields after for submission but not all the fields.

Comment: Did you gave a try at my answer ? :)

Answer (score 1):

You can use:

```
$form->get('field')->submit($defaultValue);
```

Check out [the doc](https://symfony.com/doc/2.8/form/direct_submit.html).